# Replace HTTPS to HTTPS of XML

Tags: php, xml, replace, last.fm

I need to get an image url from a XML file, but my server got some errors because this url uses https. How can I read the https link and relace it to http? Please help me, I don't understand programming...

```
function api_lastfm( $artist, $api_key ) {
        $data = xml2array( get( "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=" . urlencode( $artist ) . "&api_key={$api_key}", false, false, false, 6 ) );
        return ( isset( $data[ 'artist' ][ 'image' ][ 4 ] ) && !empty( $data[ 'artist' ][ 'image' ][ 4 ] ) ) ? $data[ 'artist' ][ 'image' ][ 4 ] : $data[ 'artist' ][ 'image' ][ 3 ];
    }
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Before you convert the XML-response (which probably is just a string), use PHP's [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function. Like: `$string = str_replace('https://lastfm-img2', 'http://lastfm-img2', $string)`. But are you sure the problem is because it is a https url?

Comment: My server log display this error message: "CURL Request "https://lastfm-img2.akamaized.net/i/u/549d31e77f614f269ca04a6bc156bda2.png" failed! LOG: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate". So I'd like to replace the https to http. Please, how my code would be? Where I put this str_replace command? Thanks.

Comment: I wrote an answer on where to do add it. It is a guess since I don't really know what your `get()` method returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my comment, use  [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for this.

My example assumes that the `get()` method returns a string with the xml:

```
function api_lastfm( $artist, $api_key ) 
{
    $data = get( "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=" . urlencode( $artist ) . "&api_key={$api_key}", false, false, false, 6 );

    // Replace all image urls using https to http
    $data = str_replace('https://lastfm-img2', 'http://lastfm-img2', $data);

    $data = xml2array($data);
    return ( isset( $data[ 'artist' ][ 'image' ][ 4 ] ) && !empty( $data[ 'artist' ][ 'image' ][ 4 ] ) ) ? $data[ 'artist' ][ 'image' ][ 4 ] : $data[ 'artist' ][ 'image' ][ 3 ];
}
```

This should change all image URL's from https to http. It does mean that the images must be available without https as well, though.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks!!

Comment: @RodrigoCaetano - If this solved your issue, please mark it as answered.